# Typescript property does not exist on extended type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react component which either takes the `to` (react-router-dom prop) or `href` prop depending on where I want to redirect the user; whether it's within the app or to an external url. Typescript complains about my type with

> Property 'to' does not exist on type 'LinkType'.

> Property 'href' does not exist on type 'LinkType'.

This is how I defined my type

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

interface LinkBase {
  label: string;
  icon?: JSX.Element;
}

interface RouterLink extends LinkBase {
  to: string;
}

interface HrefLink extends LinkBase {
  href: string;
}

type LinkType = RouterLink | HrefLink;

export function NavLink(props: LinkType) {
  const { to, label, icon, href } = props;  // TS complains about those to and href

  return(
    {to ? (
      <Link to={to}>{label}</Link>
    ) : (
      <a href={href}>{label}</a>
    )}
  );
}
```

Comment: Because LinkType is a union, HrefLink and RouterLink are both assignable to LinkType. HrefLink does not have "to" on it, and RouterLink does not have "href" on it. Therefore typescript can not guarantee that either of those properties exists on the union

Comment: @AlexD understood. Is there a way I could still destructure the props and keep the link logic?

Comment: You can access the common properties of the union, in this case label and icon, for getting the other two you need something that will narrow the type based on a conditional, see Type Guards

Comment: I provided an example of two different ways of getting this to type check properly in TypeScript

Comment: Just use `&` instead of `|` for your new `LinkType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `LinkType` is a union, `HrefLink` and `RouterLink` are both assignable to `LinkType`. `HrefLink` does not have "to" on it, and RouterLink does not have "href" on it. Therefore typescript can not guarantee that either of those properties exists on the union. You can use a type guard to do what you're trying to while also satisfying TypeScript.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

interface LinkBase {
  label: string;
  icon?: JSX.Element;
}

interface RouterLink extends LinkBase {
  to: string;
}

interface HrefLink extends LinkBase {
  href: string;
}

type LinkType = RouterLink | HrefLink;

function isRouterLink(v: unknown): v is RouterLink {
  return v && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(v, 'to');
}

function isHrefLink(v: unknown): v is HrefLink {
  return v && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(v, 'href');
}

export function NavLink(props: LinkType) {
  const { label, icon } = props; 

  if (isRouterLink(props)) {
    const { to } = props; // typechecks now
    return (<> ... </>)
  }

  if (isHrefLink(props)) {
    const { href } = props;

    return (<> ... </>);
  }

  return (<> ... </>);
}
```

Another option would be using a "tagged" union to get around the need of a type guard function. These go by some different names depending on who you're talking to. Other names you can find these by are "discriminating union" and "disjoint union" to name a couple.

```
interface LinkBase {
  label: string;
  icon?: JSX.Element;
}

interface RouterLink extends LinkBase {
  type: 'router';
  to: string;
}

interface HrefLink extends LinkBase {
  type: 'href';
  href: string;
}

type LinkType = RouterLink | HrefLink;

export function NavLink(props: LinkType) {
  const { label, icon } = props; 

  if (props.type === 'router') {
    const { to } = props; // typechecks now
    return (<> ... </>);
  }

  if (props.type === 'href') {
    const { href } = props;

    return (<> ... </>);
  }

 return (<> ... </>); 
}
```

So then if you inspect the type of `LinkType['type']` you'll see `'router' | 'href'`, and TypeScript can automatically narrow the type for you if you do an if statement on this type property of LinkType.

Comment: Yep. I also just edited the code because I noticed I was calling `hasOwnProperty` wrong, it should be `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(...)` instead of `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(...)`.

Comment: Overkilling and not scalable if you need o deal with more types in the union...

Comment: Not sure I agree. The alternative is combining all options into a single type with and making the distinct properties optional, which I don't see how that'd be more scalable given you'd still have to check that an optional property is defined before using it or risk bugs that TypeScript would be unable to statically check.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
type LinkType = RouterLink & HrefLink;
```

That way you don't have to narrow the union with code

Edit 1.
**Alex D**. raised a possible side effect of this approach.
Basically, you'll not be able to define a LinkType object without fulfilling all the properties (*href*, *label*, *to*)
This can be tackled by using Partials or simply declaring `href` and `to` as optional, e.g

```
interface HrefLink extends LinkBase {
  href?: string;
}
```

Comment: While this will get it to typecheck, I don't think it's functionally what he wants. Changing the union to an intersection will require both `href` and `to` to be in props, rather than one or the other.

Comment: @AlexD valid point, still according to the OP code, he's just accessing the properties like`const { to, label, icon, href } = props;` not creating a new object.

Comment: The concern then with using an optional property is that you're weakening the type. If he has a HrefLink, for instance, there's now no type safety on ensuring that it has a `href`. Your answer is totally valid, though, if that is not a concern of his.

Comment: This has been my initial approach to simply use optional parameters but that removes the purpose of having 2 types like RouterLink and HrefLink. I could just have those 2 optional parameters in a single type like `href?: string;` and `to?: string;`.